# Can I use Dell power adapter in MSI laptop

Tags: laptop, power-supply

I have a Msi Gf63 thin 10uc. It's DC rating is 20volt-6A. The power brick has been failed. I couldn't find the original one. My brother has a Dell power adapter which is 130watt 19.5volt 6.67A. Both msi and Dell power adapter has the same pin 4.5mm and the polarity also matches. Can I use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fine, but the laptop may complain.

Polarity is important, good job checking it - not just of the plug fits.

Next is the voltage. It should match roughly (±1V is safe and a bit more too probably, but it will depend on circuitry design in a particular laptop model). You're replacing 20V with 19.5V, that's well within tolerance.

It must be able to provide as much power as the laptop needs. Your original power adapter was 120W (20V × 6A = 120W) so that's the safe minimum. Dell one is 130W, so you're good.

Actually there's a chance that a slightly smaller adapter (say 100W) would be sufficient too - laptop manufacturers don't design adapters for each laptop separately, they use what they already have - but you don't really know without taking some measurements or comparing with other laptops that came with this adapter.

Finally, laptops can have some smart circuitry that lets them detect what kind of adapter is plugged in. I'm not sure if MSI does that, but if you were to use the MSI adapter with a Dell laptop, it would warn you that it's not original. But it's safe to try, because electrically it's okay.